# Obtener posición del jugador

Tags: java

No sé como realizar el siguiente método.

El encabezado es el siguiente:

```
public Position getPlayerPosition()
```

La documentación del proyecto dice lo siguiente:

Devuelve la Position donde está el jugador. Un jugador está representado por Element.Player o Element.Player_Stop.

Dicho método está en una clase definida de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Level {

    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int UNLIMITED_LIVES = -1;
    private final int size;
    private LevelDifficulty difficulty;

    /**
     * 2D array representing each cell in the game board.
     */
    private Cell[][] board;
    private int numMoves = 0;
    private int numLives;
    private int numGemsGot = 0;
    private final int numGemsInit;
    private final UndoStack undoStack;
```

En dicha clase tengo definido los siguiente métodos, los cuáles quizás puedan ayudar con mi problema:

```
private Cell[][] getBoard(){
        return board;
    }

public Cell getCell(int row, int column) throws LevelException{


        if(row<0||column<0) {
            throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
        }

        return board[row][column];

    }

public void setCell(Position position, Element element) throws LevelException{
        if(element!=null){
            if((position.getRow() >= 0) && (position.getColumn() >= 0) && (position.getColumn() < getSize()) && (position.getColumn()< getSize())){
                Cell  cell = new Cell(position, element);
                board[position.getRow()][position.getColumn()]=cell;
            }else{
                throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
            }
        }
    }
```

La clase Position está definida así:

```
public class Position {

private int row;
private int column;

public Position  (int row, int column) throws PositionException {
setRow(row)
setColumn(column)}
```

La clase Element es una enumeración:

```
public enum Element {

    EMPTY, EXTRA_LIFE,GEM,MINE,PLAYER, PLAYER_STOP,STOP, WALL;
}
```

Por otro lado la definición de la clase Cell es la siguiente:

```
public class Cell {

    private Position position;
    private Element element;

    public Cell(Position position, Element element){
        setPosition(position);
        setElement(element);
    }
}
```

¿Como podría acceder a la Position de una Cell donde el elemento sea Player o Player_Stop?

Answer (score 0):

Como tienes este metodo:

```
public void setCell(Position position, Element element) throws LevelException{
    if(element!=null){
        if((position.getRow() >= 0) && (position.getColumn() >= 0) && (position.getColumn() < getSize()) && (position.getColumn()< getSize())){
            Cell  cell = new Cell(position, element);
            board[position.getRow()][position.getColumn()]=cell;
        }else{
            throw new LevelException(LevelException.INCORRECT_CELL_POSITION);
        }
    }
}
```

allí esta creando una Cell si element no es null, entonces podrías hacer esto:

```
public Position getPlayerPosition(Cell cell){
  return cell.getPosition();
}
```

Eso si debes asegurarte de tener ese getter en tu clase Cell.

Comment: El método getPlayerPosition() no tiene parámetros. Sí, clase Cell posee el método público getPosition().

Comment: @NoVa deberías entregar mas contexto donde tienes dicho método, o si debes implementarlo por primera vez.